# How to write a QueryOver for a hierarchy structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

I have the following hierarchy in my database structure -

> One **JobOrder** has Many **Templates**
>
> One **Template** has Many **Groups**
>
> One **Group** has Many **Items**
>
> One **Item** has one **Status** and one **Status** has one **Item** (One to One)

I have mapped these tables to my models in NHibernate and it is also working correctly.
The one - to - one relationship has been mapped this way -

**Item.hbm.xml:**

```
<one-to-one name="Status" class="ItemStatus"></one-to-one>
```

**Status.hbm.xml:**

```
 <id name="Id" column="Id" type="long">
  <generator class="foreign" >
    <param name="property">Item</param>
  </generator>
 </id>
 <one-to-one name="Item" class="ItemInGroup" constrained="true"></one-to-one>
```

I want to write an nhibernate QueryOver which would return all the job orders which have atleast one item in its hierarchy whose status is null.

I tried writing the following -

```
var jobOrders =
            Repository.QueryOver<Models.JobOrder>().Where(
                jo => jo.Templates.Any(t => t.Groups.Any(g => g.Items.Any(i => i.Status==  
                    null)))).List();
```

But it throws the exception -

> Unrecognised method call: System.Linq.Enumerable:Boolean Any[TSource](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource], System.Func`2[TSource,System.Boolean])

How do I write this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JoinQueryOver` or `JoinAlias`.

Somthing like this should work (not tested, but you should get the idea):

```cs
var jobOrders = Repository
    .QueryOver<Models.JobOrder>()
    .JoinQueryOver<Models.Template>(j => j.Templates)
    .JoinQueryOver<Models.Group>(t => t.Groups)
    .JoinQueryOver<Models.Item>(g => g.Items)
    .Where(i => i.Status == null)
    .List<Models.JobOrder>();
```